# List files which have a corresponding "ready" file

Tags: linux, shell

I have a service "A" which generates some compressed files comprising of the data it receives in requests. In parallel there is another service "B" which consumes these compressed files.

The trick is "B" shouldn't consume any of the files unless they are written completely. The service deduces this information by looking for a ".ready" file created by service "A" with name exactly same as the file generated along with the extension mentioned; once the compression is done. Service "B" uses Apache Camel to do this filtering.

Now, I am writing a shell script which needs the same compressed files and  this would need the same filtering be implemented in shell. I need help writing this script. I am aware of ***find*** command but a naive shell user, so have very limited knowledge.

> Example:
>
> Compressed file: sumit_20171118_1.gz
>
> Corresponding ready
> file: sumit_20171118_1.gz.ready
>
> Another compressed file: sumit_20171118_2.gz
>
> No ready file is present for this one.

Of the above listed files only the first should be picked up as it has a corresponding ready file.

Comment: Why don't you just loop over all `*.ready` files, then cut off the `.ready` suffix?

Comment: Yes, certainly an option. I was just wondering if there exists some command/ in built functionality which does this. Or in general if there is a standard way to approach such cases.

Comment: If **Service B** is looking for compressed files, the way it normally works is that **Service A** writes the files with an extension like `.inprogress` and when the file is completely written, **Service A** changes its name to end in `.gz` - thereby atomically releasing a complete file to **Service B**.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Agree, but let's say it can't be changed right away due to some other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way would be to use a busy loop. But if you are on GNU/Linux you can do better than that (from: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-GNU-Parallel-as-dir-processor)

```
inotifywait -qmre MOVED_TO -e CLOSE_WRITE --format %w%f my_dir |
  parallel -uj1 echo Do stuff to file {}
```

This way you do not even have to wait for the .ready file: The command will only be run when writing to the file is finished and the file is closed.

If, however, the .ready file is only written much later then you can search for that one:

```
inotifywait -qmre MOVED_TO -e CLOSE_WRITE --format %w%f my_dir |
  grep --line-buffered '\.ready$' |
  parallel -uj1 echo Do stuff to file {.}
```